PWA missbehaving when using keycloak behind Traefik
I have a simple single page vue app served by a lighttpd instance behind keycloak and traefik.
I can then access the site with https and am asked to log in because keycloak realizes I am not logged in.
The app works as expected.
However, when installed as a PWA in android it will at first work after logging in, but be broken the next day.
What I assume is happening, is that the keycloak session expires, and that the vue app is unable to make requests. However, because the index.html is static content the browser does not reload it, serving the cached page, and does not show the login screen.
How to work around? I would prefer not to have to change the single page app.
